# Can't able to delete inbox sms

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I want to delete inbox sms by clicking on particular listview. I tried alot but cant able to do this. Android version is 4.1.2. kindly help. I've shown inbox by this function:

```
public void refreshInbox(){
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver(); // get content resolver to select database
        Cursor inboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
        int indexAddress = inboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address"); //get index of address column
        int indexBody = inboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body"); //get index of message body column
        if(indexBody < 0 || !inboxCursor.moveToFirst()) {return;};
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        do {
            String str = "Sms from: " +inboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) + "\n"
                    + inboxCursor.getString(indexBody);
            arrayAdapter.add(str);
        } while (inboxCursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

and trying to delete sms by clicking on listview via this function:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver(); // get content resolver to select database
                        Cursor c = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
                        //int idd = c.getInt(0);
                        int thread_id = c.getInt(1); //get the thread_id
                        getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + thread_id),null,null);
```

AndroidManifist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zohaib.ultimatesmsblocker">

    <!-- Give permission to read, receive, send sms -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter android:priority="10000">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".conversation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_conversation"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Blocklist"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_blocklist"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Which Android version are you running under?

Comment: Android version 4.1.2

Comment: is my syntax correct? @MikeM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Delete SMS at particular threadId location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104316/android-delete-sms-at-particular-threadid-location)

Comment: If you're trying to delete a single message, you want the `_id`, not the `thread_id`. If you're trying to delete a whole thread, then the delete `Uri` is wrong. Furthermore, after the inbox query, you need to move the `Cursor` to a row before retrieving values; e.g., `c.moveToFirst()`. Also, you shouldn't use hard-code column indexes. Use the `getColumnIndex()` method like you've done in the first code block.

Comment: I would also point out that your code is just going to delete a rather arbitrary message, as you're not tying the message IDs to the list items in any way.

Comment: can you give me this type of running example code?

Comment: i didn't have concrete concept of Uri. if you give me the running example code then it will most useful.

Comment: I would recommend testing your delete function first, before tackling the `ListView` data set. Judging from your description, you just want to delete a single message at a time. In that case, `content://sms/` is correct, but you want to append `idd`, not `thread_id`. Also, add `c.moveToFirst();` after the inbox query, and change `c.getInt(0)` to `c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"))`. That code block should then delete the most recent message in your inbox. Test it out.

Comment: I forgot to mention, make sure you have the `WRITE_SMS` permission listed in your manifest.

Comment: thanks also tell me what is the column name for getting user name from inbox. similarly in this case inboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address"); the column name is "address". I also need to get ColumnIndex of name column. @MikeM.

Comment: great thanks you help me alot..